# Copying text with color from Notepad++

Tags: text, colors, copy, notepad++

Is there a way to copy the text from a Notepad ++ file with color?

I am trying to write a tutorial document, and I would to be able to
copy the xml tags.

Thanks!

Answer (score 195):

There's a plugin called NppExport that does just that in a couple of available formats. If you don't have NppExport yet, you can download it through the inbuilt plugin manager.

*update* As of version 6.1.5 (or maybe earlier) this ships with a standard install of Notepad++

[image]

*update* As of 2019 `NppExport` is not included by default in the `Notepad++ 64 bits` version ([github issue](http://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3042)). You can download the 64 bits version of NppExport here: [[github](http://github.com/chcg/NPP_ExportPlugin/releases)]

Comment: Incredible. I'm so happy that this exists, though it would be even nicer if the default Edit > Copy command provided RTF as a default for MS Word, Outlook etc.

Comment: FYI Notepad++ v7.2.2 this is not included anymore and adding the plugin manually reports its broken.

Comment: but it seems to takes the (black in my case) background color with it, so it outputs a black line

Comment: For anyone wondering why it doesn't have NppExport installed nor the plugin manager to install it, https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/2459

Comment: `NppExport` is not included by default in the `Notepad++ 64 bits` version (an issue https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3042 has been opened for this to be the case).

You can download the 64 bits version of `NppExport` here : https://github.com/chcg/NPP_ExportPlugin/releases

Comment: In Notepad++ v7.7.1, NppExport maintains font name, size, and bold, but not font color. Works fine in 7.6.x. See: [NppExport plugin - 'copy HTML to clipboard' does not work anymore](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17716/nppexport-plugin-copy-html-to-clipboard-does-not-work-anymore)

Comment: The from Eliaha to NPP [Community forum page](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17716/nppexport-plugin-copy-html-to-clipboard-does-not-work-anymore/16) has a post that links to Github page.  Download the zip from Github, extract the contents.  Download: https://github.com/chcg/NPP_ExportPlugin/releases/tag/0.2.9.21.  The only file in the zip is `NppExport.dll`.  Copy it into you your Notepad++ program folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\NppExport`).  This simple update fixed the issue where **"Copy HTML to clipboard"** does not get the font colors.  Yay :-)

Comment: NppExport version 0.2.8 was not pasting the syntax formatting colors for me.  I am happy that updating to 0.2.9 fixed the colors. :-)

Answer (score 19):

In NPP v6.7.7 you can do this by selecting your text, right clicking on it, select "Plugin commands" and then "Copy text with syntax highlighting".

Comment: There's also "copy html" under "NppExport" in the plugins menu

Answer (score 1):

To built on Raveren answer : 
Copy HTML to clipboard didn't for me (for a .bat), I had to select plugins/NppExport/Export to HTML instead and then open the html in a browser and copy the text from there.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine when you choose copy with right click plugin commands and copy text with syntax highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

For Notepad++ 64-bit releases you can find the NppExport plugin here: https://github.com/chcg/NPP_ExportPlugin/releases

I've tested "NppExport_0.2.8.16_x64.zip" with Notepad++ v7.5.4.

Answer (score 0):

For copying .bat file contents,  simply choose the 'Copy all formats to Clipboard' Option.

Comment: Is there a way to make 'Copy all formats to Clipboard' the default action for Ctrl-C / Edit > Copy ? I would always want that available. Pasting that back to NP++ seems not to cause any problem, it pastes the plain text only.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way worked for me is:

1. Print your contents from npp++ to pdf by using microsoft print to
   pdf tool ( It will retain all the formatting and color code in pdf).

   2. Open that pdf file by using Microsoft Word and it will ask you
      the confirmation for conversion to word, convert it.
   3. If you want to make changes to the file just save save as the file with 'save
      as' option and that's it.

Answer (score -1):

I have downloaded plugin Manager from https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases. It contains Plugin Manager DLL and an EXE. Copy paste PluginManager.dll into C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins and Copy paste gpup.exe into C:\Program Files\Notepad++\updater. If you dont have updater folder, create one. Restart notepad ++. Under Plugins-->YOu will notice Plugin Manager. Use this to install Plugins. The one I installed is NppExport. This is very use full.